# Error parsing 'parameters' JSON Watson Visual Recognition

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, visual-recognition

I am getting the below error while calling Watson Visual Recognition API through Java. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
       VisualRecognition service = new VisualRecognition(VisualRecognition.VERSION_DATE_2016_05_20);
       service.setApiKey("api_key");

       InputStream imagesStream = new FileInputStream("C:\\fruitbowl.jpg");
       ClassifyOptions classifyOptions =
               new ClassifyOptions.Builder().imagesFile(imagesStream).imagesFilename("fruitbowl.jpg")
                       .parameters("{\"classifier_ids\": [\"fruits_1462128776\", + \"SatelliteModel_6242312846\"],\"threshold\": 0.6}")
                       .build();
       ClassifiedImages result = service.classify(classifyOptions).execute();
       System.out.println(result);
```

Stacktrace:

```
  SEVERE: POST https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition  /api/v3/classify?version=2016-05-20&api_key=0b5b96d2428f020c207a9388f2bb1ee840e57c9c, status: 400, error: {
"error": {
    "code": 400,
    "error_id": "input_error",
    "description": "Error parsing 'parameters' JSON. Ensure threshold is a float; owner and classifier-ids are string arrays; url is a string."
}}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is the `+` in the middle of your parameters string.  I think it should be:

```
.parameters("{\"classifier_ids\": [\"fruits_1462128776\", \"SatelliteModel_6242312846\"],\"threshold\": 0.6}")
                   .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message refers to `classifier-ids` and you have `classifier_ids`, so it could be down to a simple typo. Although the documentation also has `classifier_ids` in the example - https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/visual-recognition/api/v3/?java#classify_an_image